# Multiline regex with groups

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regex Python 2.7 (for Abaqus) and need to partition the following lines of code:

```
fin2Text:
(...)
7, 4, 8
8, 8, 2
*ELEMENT, type=CPS3, ELSET=Surface1
9, 5, 6, 7
10, 5, 8, 6
11, 1, 5, 7
12, 2, 8, 5
13, 7, 6, 3
14, 8, 4, 6
*ELSET,ELSET=setWPbot
1, 2, 1, 2, 
(...)
```

How can I tell Python to give me all the lines under a certain string (here it is '*ELEMENT, type=CPS3, ELSET=Surface1') with an unknown number of lines.

Currently, I use this

```
patternOldGeoElem = re.compile('\*ELEMENT,\stype=CPS3,\sELSET=Surface1\n(((\d+),\s(\d+),\s(\d+),\s(\d+)\n?){1,})')
matchesOldGeoElem = re.findall(patternOldGeoElem, fin2Text)
```

I get a result with this, but the problem is that the grouping still doesn't work as expected, because I want to save all the digits into an array or dictionary, like this:

```
elemArray = [
['elemNum', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3'],
[9,5,6,7],
[10,5,8,7],
[11,1,5,7],
[12,2,8,5],
[13,7,6,3],
[14,8,4,6]]
```

I'm looking forward to any kind of help or advice.

Comment: Never used Python, but do a lot with PowerShell. Why not a little string manipulation of the resulting match. Looks like this in PowerShell (`$Data` your text, `$rx` the regex stirng):`$data -match $rx; $matches[0] -split "``n" | ForEach{
$el = $_.Split(',');
'elNum: {0} Data: {1}, {2}, {3}' -f $el[0], $el[1], $el[2], $el[3]
}` (-f just used to demonstrate accessing individual elements)

Comment: Newline is '`n', had to double up to keep code block...